# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s using Three20 and iOS6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios6, armv7

Trying to update our app for iOS6 and iPhone 5, we (for now) still aren't able to completely move away from the Facebook Three20 library.

When debugging in the simulator for iPhone and iPad, everything works perfectly fine. When attempting to debug on an iPhone 5, we get the following failures:

```
 ld: warning: ignoring file ..../Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): ..../Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20.a
```

Followed by:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TTTabItem", referenced from:
```

Is there a way to relink/rebuild the Three20 library for my target to ensure that it properly builds for armv7 and works correctly on the iPhone 5 for debugging?

I've tried messing around with the Projects' build settings, etc, but have not had any success getting this resolved.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After fiddling around for an hour I realized that I needed to go to my project, and for each attached Three20 project select it, go to that project's Build Settings, and manually update the Architectures to the new required armv7, armv7s.